# Reading memory from given 24-bit address

Tags: x86

I need to read memory from the address:

```
0C0003H
```

and move it to AL register. Will I achieve this using simple:

```
MOV al, [0C0003H]
```

? I guess it cannot be that simple...AL is 8-bit register, the address is 24-bit. How can I do this then?

Also, why there are 24 bits in this address? Shouldn't it be more like 16 or 32 bits? Why have they added 0 at the beginning just to increase the number of bits from 20 to 24?

Comment: If you have 2^24 8-bit values you're going to need 24-bit addresses to address them all.

Comment: It is 32 bits. The leading 0 is to ensure that the value is treated as a number rather than a variable name. Without the leading 0, it would be treated as a variable named `C0003H`.

Comment: How can I move the memory from that address into 8 bit register?

Comment: If you only want to load a single byte, what you have should suffice (although without any context, it's hard to say that it's "right"). If you want to load a 16, 32 or 64-bit quantity, the instruction name and register name would have to be different, and depending on what assembler you use, there may be additional syntax required...

Comment: Instructions must be written in ASM16 if it clears anything...

Answer (score 0):

You can reference below code to access one byte from that address in assembly:

```
push 0000h
pop es
mov ebx, 0C0003h
mov al, es:[ebx]; where es:ebx is used as the memory pointer
```